# Ellipse not correctly rotating using the general equation of ellipse

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections, python

I have generated a set of y coordinates for a given set of x coordinates using the following generalized equation of ellipse:

$$\dfrac {((x-h)\cos(A)+(y-k)\sin(A))^2}{(a^2)}+\dfrac{((x-h) \sin(A)-(y-k) \cos(A))^2}{(b^2)}=1$$

This is the quadratic form of the equation given above:
$$y^2(\dfrac{sin^2(A)}{b^2} + \dfrac{cos^2(A)}{a^2}) + y(2xsin(A)cos(A)(\dfrac {1}{a^2} - \dfrac {1}{b^2})) + (x^2(\dfrac{cos^2(A)}{b^2}+\dfrac{sin^2(A)}{a^2}) - 1)$$

The equation is in quadratic form:
$$y^2Q + yW + C$$

I have managed to simplify the equation down to a quadratic form so that i can solve the equation, but i'm not able to rotate the ellipse by using values other than 0(zero) for **A** *(which is the angle)*.

Ellipse with **A = 0**:

[image: ellipse 1]

Ellipse with **A = 1**:

[image]

Ellipse with **A = 10**:

[image: ellipse 2]

As you can see, the ellipse is not being constructed correctly for angles other than 0. What am i doing wrong? I'm using python to construct the ellipse.

PS: Let the set of x coordinate points be [1, 10].

Comment: In your second equation, the first $b$ in the denominator should be squared. Also: you might want to try $A = .0001$, to see whether that works. What values are you using for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Also: why are you using the implicit form for the ellipse? It's really easy to write a parameterized ellipse by translating, rotating, and scaling a standard circle, which you parameterize with $(\cos t, \sin t)$ and $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yeah, $b$ was a typo, fixed it now. I wasn't aware of the parameterized equation. I'm kind of a newb in this area of maths. I'll try the parameterized form.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes! The parameterized form worked perfectly! Also as you suggested, its very easy to implement too! Thankyou so much! Could you post it as the answer so that i could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: Instead of the implicit form, you might want to use the parameterized form of a circle $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$, $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, and transform it by scaling (to make it elliptical), rotating (to put the axes in the direction you want) and then translating (to move it to the location you want).